# Creating an N x N array of integers that "staircase" and "wrap around"

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, for-loop

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to get data ordered like below. The total numbers don't matter; it would follow the same pattern from any number in the logical order of 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, etc. So essentially, starting at 0, 2, 3, 4, etc. where 1 would be placed *after* the maximum number, and where 0 can be a variable I set statically. I am having issues with progressing all the way to max number and then continuing, *e.g.*

```
..., 97, 98, 99, 100, 1, 2, ...
```

and then progressing with the order,

```
..., 98, 99, 100, 1, 2, 3, ...
```

and so on until 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...

and store this all into the multidimensional array below.

```
$set = array(
    array('0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'),
    array('0','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1'),
    array('0','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2'),
    array('0','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3'),
    array('0','5','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4'),
    array('0','6','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5'),
    array('0','7','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6'),
    array('0','8','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7'),
    array('0','9','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'),
    array('0','10','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'),
    array('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'),
);
```

I did the above because I couldn't figure out a looping pattern; if I could figure that out I wouldn't need to enter in the data manually and could create a form by which any number could be chosen, following this pattern.

Comment: You're trying to build an `N x M` array, where you simply have numbers 'stair casing'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that other than the first row and column, each row is just the previous shifted left, with the next value added on:

```
$max = 10;

// First row (full of 0)
$set = array(array_fill(0, $max + 1, 0));

$row = array();
for($i = 1; $i <= $max; $i++)
    $row[] = $i;
$row[] = 1; // $row  = [2,3,4,...,$max,1]

for($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++){
    $set[] = array_merge(array(0), $row);
    $row = array_map(function($x) use ($max){ // Requires PHP 5.3
        $result = ($x + 1) % $max;
        return 0 === $result ? $max : $result;
    }, $row);
}
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/NszW9n)

It's of course fairly trivial to make this store strings instead of integers if you require that.

Comment: Thank you! This is perfect, I am going to do some research to figure out the function($x) because I'd really like to understand what's going on! At any length this does the trick very well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array();
$max = 10;
for ($i = 0; $i < $max; $i++)
{
    $num = $i + 2;
    $array[$i][] = 0;
    for ($j = 0; $j < $max; $j++)
    {
        if ($num == $max + 1)
            $num = 1;
        $array[$i][] = $num;
        $num++;
    }
}
var_dump($array);
```